# Passing string varaible to native method

Tags: java, string, java-native-interface

I'm trying to pass two strings to a native method, the method doesn't execute while passing strings like this

```
String pathDir=request.getParameter("path");
String user=request.getParameter("user");
obj.modifyACL(pathDir, user, 'a', 1);
```

The same method executes well when passing strings as this

```
obj.modifyACL("C:/Users/margie/Desktop/tb.h", "SYSTEM", 'r', 2);
```

The value of pathDir and users are not empty while getting the HTML element value. I used

```
pw.println(user+pathDir);
```

and it shows like this

> SYSTEM C:\Users\margie\Desktop\tb.h

This is native method

```
PACL SetPerm(LPCTSTR file, string user, char val, int perm, PACL pOldDACL)
{
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS eas[1];
    PACL pacl = 0;
    DWORD rc;
    long long int access_val;
    LPSTR use = const_cast<char *>(user.c_str());
    if(val=='R'||val=='r')
        access_val=0x80000000;      //GENERIC_READ
    if(val=='W'||val=='w')
        access_val=0x40000000;      //GENERIC_WRITE
    if(val=='A'||val=='a')
        access_val=0x10000000;      //GENERIC_ALL
    if(perm==1)
    {
        eas[0].grfAccessPermissions = access_val;
        eas[0].grfAccessMode = GRANT_ACCESS;
        eas[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
        eas[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
        eas[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
        eas[0].Trustee.ptstrName = use;
    }
    else if(perm==2)
    {
        eas[0].grfAccessPermissions = access_val;
        eas[0].grfAccessMode = DENY_ACCESS;
        eas[0].grfInheritance = NO_INHERITANCE;
        eas[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
        eas[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
        eas[0].Trustee.ptstrName = use;
    }
    rc = SetEntriesInAcl(1, eas, pOldDACL, &pacl);
    if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("ERROR---------SetEntriesInAcl: %u\n", rc);
        return NULL;
    }

    rc = SetNamedSecurityInfo((LPSTR)file, SE_FILE_OBJECT,
             DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
             NULL, NULL, pacl, NULL);
    if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("ERROR---------SetNamedSecurityInfo: %u\n", rc);
        return NULL;
    }

    cout << "----------------PERMISSION GRANTED----------------\n";
    return pacl;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_total_modifyACL(JNIEnv *env, jobject thisObj, jstring inJNIStr, jstring inStr, jchar chr, jint num)
{
cout<<"Inside modifyACL()\n";
PSID pSidOwner = NULL;
DWORD dwRtnCode = 0, dwAcctName = 1, dwDomainName = 1;
HANDLE hFile;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
PACL pOldDACL = NULL;
char ch;
char tp=(char)chr;
int val,i,aceNum;
int perm=(int)num;

const char *input = env->GetStringUTFChars(inJNIStr, NULL);
const char *user = env->GetStringUTFChars(inStr, NULL);

// Get the handle of the file object.
hFile = CreateFile(
                  input,
                  GENERIC_READ,
                  FILE_SHARE_READ,
                  NULL,
                  OPEN_EXISTING,
                  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                  NULL);

// Check GetLastError for CreateFile error code.
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;
          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          cout << "CreateFile error = " << dwErrorCode<<". Possibly NO file exist in the given path or READ Access denied.";
          exit;
}

// Get the SID of the file.
dwRtnCode = GetSecurityInfo(
                  hFile,
                  SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                  DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                  &pSidOwner,
                  NULL,
                  &pOldDACL,
                  NULL,
                  &pSD);

// Check GetLastError for GetSecurityInfo error condition.
if (dwRtnCode != ERROR_SUCCESS) {
          DWORD dwErrorCode = 0;
          dwErrorCode = GetLastError();
          cout << "GetSecurityInfo error = " << dwErrorCode;
}
    pOldDACL = SetPerm(input,user,tp,perm,pOldDACL);        //passing pOldDACL to add the ACE in exixting ACE.
}
```

What should I do to make modifyACL() work on passing user input string?

Comment: I have added the native method code. Please check it out. @SomeDude

Comment: What does "doesn't execute" mean? It's blank? Crashes? Print `input` and `user` in your native method and see if they're what you expect. Also, you need to call `ReleaseStringUTFChars()` or else you'll leak 2 strings each time.

Comment: It's blank, no output. @TainToTain

Comment: Where is the jni glue code? Where do you convert the Java types to native types?

Comment: You mean this? const char *input = env->GetStringUTFChars(inJNIStr, NULL);
const char *user = env->GetStringUTFChars(inStr, NULL); @Botje

Comment: Ah, forgot to scroll down. Sorry.

Comment: Are you compiling this code in UNICODE mode? If so, LPCTSTR expects a UTF-16 (two-byte) string instead of UTF-8 (one-byte). Even if you did not set UNICODE,know that that string is interpreted according to the system locale, which is very probably not UTF-8 but some thing like cp1252.

Comment: Also check that "request" actually has the parameter values you think it has.

Comment: Yeah request parameter is not null as I mentioned already. If printing that parameters value its showing. @user2543253

Comment: Can u please explain more? @Botje

Comment: See the [Microsoft documentation on TCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings)

Comment: Also, if GetStringUTFChars returns null, make sure there is no pending exception.

Comment: And get yourself a C++ IDE with a debugger